# NoSuchElementException infinite loop vs. pmd DD-anomaly

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, pmd, nosuchelementexception

I'm kinda new to programming and very new to gradle and the pmd-plugin, so please have mercy.

If the user enters a number, scanner.nextLine() will throw a NoSuchElementException in every iteration thus creating an infinite loop.

```
public class Console {
    public int readInteger(String line) {
        Integer x = null;
        while(x == null) {
            try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) {
                System.out.print(line);
                x = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch(InputMismatchException exc) {
                  //error message
            } catch(InvalidStateException exc) {
                  //error message
            } catch(NoSuchElementException exc) {
                 //error message
            }
        }
        return x;    
    }
}
```

I will appreciate every helping hand.

Edit: Realized, that my problem occurs in conjuction with the Scanner.nextLine() method. The order doesn't matter, my loop is still an infinite loop with the same NoSuchElementException.

Comment: What is the input you are entering?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the

```
x = scanner.nextLine();
```

to

```
x = scanner.nextInt();
```

Also no it will not enter infinite loop because you use wrong method it simply will not work .

Comment: scanner.nextLine() was a mistake, didn't copy the code, just remembered it and wrote it into the question. is fixed, but the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete (compilable) example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Console {
    public int readInteger(String line) {
        Integer x = null;
        while(x == null) {
            try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                System.out.print(line);
                x = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch(InputMismatchException exc) {
                  //error message
            } catch(IllegalStateException exc) {
                  //error message
            } catch(NoSuchElementException exc) {
                 //error message
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console c = new Console();
        int age = c.readInteger("How old are you? ");
        System.out.printf("You are %d years old.%n", age);
    }
}
```

Note: InvalidStateException doesn't exist, it is IllegalStateException.

Save this code snippet in `Console.java` and run it with java 11+ like `java Console.java`.

If you are entering eg. `42` it works. The "endless loop" starts, if you don't enter an integer, e.g. `very old`. Now we need to actually handle the exceptions. In that case, `InputMismatchException` will be thrown. But the wrong input is not consumed and is still in the scanner - so trying again with `nextInt()` will throw the same exception again. We'll have to read the wrong token first before the user can enter new data. We can read the data with `nextLine()`, but therefore we need to have access to the scanner, so we need to open the scanner instance earlier - and have the loop and error handling inside the outer try-with-resources.

If the user closes the input stream (with `Ctlr+Z` under Windows or `Cltr+D` under Linux), then `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown, so we'll need to handle that case as well. `IllegalStateException` will be thrown, if the Scanner instance itself is closed.

Here's a fixed complete example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Console {
    public int readInteger(String line) {
        Integer x = null;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while(x == null) {
                try {
                    System.out.print(line);
                    x = scanner.nextInt();
                } catch(InputMismatchException exc) {
                    String wrongInput = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.printf("The input '%s' is not a number. Please try again.%n", wrongInput);
                } catch(NoSuchElementException exc) {
                   // no input provided
                   System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console c = new Console();
        int age = c.readInteger("How old are you? ");
        System.out.printf("You are %d years old.%n", age);
    }
}
```